# How to create this custom flowchart in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flowchart

I need help creating this flow chart  in flutter. I've tried packages like graphite and syncfusion but they dont do the job. Any help is appreciated.
[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2aQL.png)

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/graphite

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but, like I said in the question, graphite does not do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a similar look using a custom painter in flutter.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by editing the svg code and adding variables to colors and texts, thereby making them dynamic.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).